# Java method percentage

Tags: java, methods, decimal, percentage

I was hoping someone from SO can help me with my code. So the whole point of the program is to ask the user to enter the wholesale price for the item they want. Then they enter the markup percentage for that item. The program them figures out the retail price. An example is if the user enters 5 for the wholesale then enters .100 (100%) for the markup price, the retail price would then be 10 dollars. My trouble is that when ever I enter the decimal for the percentage it gives me an these errors:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
at RetailPrice.main(RetailPrice.java:10)
```

It will help if anyone can give me any advice as to what is going wrong, I'm trying to self teach java and any help/tips would be great!

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in); //make a scanner

    System.out.println("Enter the wholesale cost of the item");
    double cost = keyboard.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter the markup percent as a decimal");
    double percent = keyboard.nextInt();
    caculateRetail(cost, percent);
}

public static void caculateRetail(double cost, double percent)
{
    double total = cost * (cost*percent);
    System.out.println("The retail price is $"+ total);
}
```

}

Comment: Why don't you use `nextDouble`, not `nextInt`?

Comment: `.100` is not an *integer* value. It is also *not* 100%, because the *floating-point* number `1.00` would be 100%. It doesn't matter how many zeroes you add at the end after a decimal point, `0.1`, `0.10`, `0.100`, `0.1000`, ... are all 10%.

Comment: Integers cannot contain decimal point.  That is why Andrew Li suggested using `nextDouble`.  Also your formula is incorrect, it should be `double total = cost * ( 1.0 + percent / 100.0);`

Comment: Well now I feel really stupid for those mistakes. Thank you guys for the help.

Comment: @JohnSmth feel free to upvote the accepted answer.